# From a view can I call a method in the controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

In a view how do you call a method in the controller or another class in the project?  Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need call action method inside your view you need use `ChildActionOnly` :

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult action1()
{
   //
   return PartialView();
}
```

then in your view :

```
@Html.Partial("action1")
```

but if you want to call a method like helper class, simply you can this way :

```
@helper ShowTree()
{
   //some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Below mention all format to how to view call controller action events.

-> Call with Ajax beginform

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ContainerSizeDetail", "Content", FormMethod.Post, null, new { @class = "" }))
        {}
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ContainerSizeDetail(ContainerSizeModel model)
        {}
```

-> Call with Beginform

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("VendorContactDetail", "VendorAccount", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmVendorContact" }))
                {}
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult VendorContactDetail()
        {}
```

-> Call with Ajax call

```
        var request = $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost/ProjectDirectory/VendorAccount/ValidateUser",
                        type: 'POST',
                        cache: false,
                        data: JSON.stringify(returnValue),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    });

[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ValidateUser(VendorRegistrationModel model)
        {}
```